# JCA Connection Pool in Wildfly, how to get the current pool state

Tags: command-line-interface, wildfly8, connection-pool

I have a Wildfly 9 and one of our JCA Resource Adapter Connection Pools is getting full, so no more connections can be requested.

As far as I can tell by now, this is the expected load and I am not loosing connections anywhere (but I keep investigating this). So I need to find out how large the pool needs to be and how to increase it.

To this end I need a command line query that requests information about the pool from the running wildfly instance.

The problem I'm investigating manifests in this error message:

```
javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/eis/MyResourceAdapter
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:646)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:552)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:737)
    [... omitted deployment specific calls ...]
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:553)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:622)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:594)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:579)
```

Note: If someone with sufficient privileges would create and add the 'wildfly' and/or 'wildfly9' tag, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the server in the bin folder try running:

```
./jboss-cli.sh
connect
/subsystem=jca:read-resource(include-runtime=true,recursive=true)
```

So run the client, run connect, and then paste in the third line including the /

I don't mess around with Wildfly too much but I think this can work, it works with JBoss.

Comment: I tried this command and it produced some information, but not the amount of connections in the pool. Could you add a default output from your server where you highlight the place where the connectionamount is written?

Comment: Is it jca pool getting full or datasource?

Comment: I have amended my question with the concrete error message, I understand it to mean that the connection pool is getting full.